# Kerr spacetime and Carter time machine

Tags: black-holes, time-travel, kerr-metric, closed-timelike-curve

In the Boyer-Lindquist-Block III (inside the inner event horizon) exists the so-called Carter time machine. There we can show that for any two points $p,q$ there exists a future-pointing timelike or past-pointing timelike curve.

I'm not sure if I understood what "past-pointing" means?

Why does this effect imply a "time machine"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose a spacetime has a global time function: a globally defined difference between past and future. Then we can divide timelike curves into two classes. When the proper time along a "future-pointing" curve advances, so does the global time. When the proper time along a "past-pointing" curve advances, the global time *goes backwards*.

In the Kerr-Carter time-machine there exist so-called "closed timelike lines" that *reverse* their temporal orientation. An observer along one of those lines starts off moving into the future, but ends up travelling into the past. Thus the term "time-machine": as my wristwatch time advances, the world around me seems to move backwards in time. I could in principle follow the curve for a while, and then change my acceleration to follow a different future-directed curve, effectively travelling back in time. Hence the term 'time machine'.

It's worth pointing out that Block 3 of the Kerr black hole has been shown to be generically unstable, so I wouldn't take this too seriously.

Comment: Can you explain or give me a reference to "generically unstable".  I am studying the Kerr metric in an attempt to disprove the "time machine" and instability is last in my list of thoughts (it seems like a cheat).