# Can I get turned around backwards in time?

Tags: spacetime, metric-tensor, geodesics

On a surface embedded in Euclidian space, where the metric signature is all positive, it is possible for a particle traveling along a geodesic to encounter a curved bit and then get turned around so that it heads in the opposite direction.

Could there be a manifold that did the same turning-around trick, but in a timelike direction? Would this create particles for which increasing proper time corresponded to decreasing coordinate time?

Comment: for an outside observer, that would look exactly like particle annihilation, except that it fails to conserve energy and that it would also create royal mess for the causal structure of the universe.

Comment: also it's unclear from your description how the anomaly should appear for the future observer. Does it also spawn an object-antiobject pair completely unrelated to what happens on its past side?

Comment: @JohnDvorak If you flipped the parameter of an object's worldline, I am pretty sure the first component of the 4-velocity and thereby the energy would go negative. As a result I'm not sure if I would agree that it fails to conserve energy. (To go from matter to antimatter I think you have to do more than flip time, although I could be wrong - isn't the full symmetry CPT or something?)

Comment: @JohnDvorak As for the causal structure of the universe, I think there is some respectable research out there on closed timelike curves, so situations with unclear causality are not beyond reasonable speculation. As for what it looks like to an outside observer, I imagine they would see an object and an unobject (not antimatter(?) ) enter the weird patch of spacetime and go away. Of course, I do not really understand what the implications of this would be which is why I posted a question. :)

Comment: Negative energy would create its own host of problems. For one, you'd have to explain why the vacuum doesn't seem to create particle-negaparticle pairs all the time.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Maybe particle-negaparticle pairs don't do anything even when created. For example they would not change the cosmological constant because they have net zero energy. I don't know enough about QFT to speak further but perhaps a solution is out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this happens when you enter or exit the inner Cauchy horizon of a rotating Kerr black hole at the right angle, see [Madore](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/kerr.html#course.white_holes)'s article and [Hamilton](https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/penrose.html#kerr)'s penrose diagram; this is sometimes referred to as the [Carter time machine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221326/kerr-spacetime-and-carter-time-machine).

Inside the inner horizon it is even possible to meet an other observer who fell through at an other angle so his proper time is going in the same direction as the coordinate time, while your proper time goes in the opposite direction, which would have weird effects since not only would you hear the other observer talk backwards, but also he would remember things that are in your future while what's in your past is in his future.

That would be even weirder if you chose to blow yourself up, then the other observer would observe an implosion that would create rather than destroy you, and a bunch of other paradox thought experiments would become possible.

The only problem is that when you go through the Cauchy horizon, you get hit by an infinite blueshifted signal (in the moment when you cross that horizon, you go to future infinity and back in an infinitesimal amount of proper time), see [Dafermos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETn6aOzwmr4&t=19m46s)'s lecture.